# ASP.NET - I do not want use master page for a page

Tags: c#, asp.net

My problem is that I cannot release my page without master page. I have a master page but I want to redesign my sign-up page, so I do not want to use the master page for the sign-up page.

If I delete master page string from register.aspx page get an error.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Hackerdot.Register" %>
```

I tried deleting `MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master"` but then the page did not compile.

P.S: I don't have the source code, I am just doing a redesign of this website.

[image]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Can you post the actual compilation error that you're getting from the IDE, and the line of code **after** you have deleted "Main.Master"?

Comment: Create a new page and don't choose a Master Page.  Copy the relevant code over to the new page.

Comment: delete asp:content tags

Comment: As I told, I do not have source codes, I just designer, I will report this to developers but I am trying to resolve myself :)

Comment: "I don't have source code". Sorry, that means that you are unable to provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which will make it difficult to provide complete answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to remove a Master Page from one of your pages, you must do the following (if they apply):

- Remove the `MasterPageFile` attribute form your `Page` directive.
- Remove the `MasterType` directive.
- Remove any `<asp:Content>` tags you have on the page.
- Remove any references to the `Master` property in your code behind (and rebuild!)

Also, any dependencies that exist in your Master Page will need to be moved down to your Page, such as a `<asp:ScriptManager>`.

Comment: Copy the `<asp:ScriptManager>` code from your master and drop it onto your page. An `<asp:UpdatePanel>` requires at least one of them to be present, I believe.

Comment: Then that means your master page has a script manager for use across your website.  If your master page is being removed from this page, and the page requires a script manager, then you need to add a script manager.

Comment: @hackerdot - You're most welcome. Updated answer in case it helps others.